# WPF DataGridCell, Style.Trigger, basedon multiple styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, datatrigger

I have got this problem with styles in WPF. 
I want every cells in row in red color. 
When I use two styles for one cell MyCellStyle and RightCellStyle (based on MyCellStyle) the result is:

[image](http://www.image-share.com/ipng-625-92.html)

Here is may code for MyCellStyle and RightCellStyle

```
<Style x:Key="MyCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedRowColor}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFDFE9F5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

```
<Style x:Key="RightCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCellStyle}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And here is part where I set red Color

```
<DataGrid.Style>
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Setter Property="CellStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyCellStyle}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsNew}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```